# Values of inputs created in a modal persist after modal removal in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using Shiny modal to provide a short questionnaire to my users. Some parts of this questionnaire are hidden by default and shown only once user selects some specific value from visible inputs.

Everything works fine the first time you use the modal, however if you want to resubmit it, the hidden part of the questionnaire is not shown. This is caused by the fact that after removing the modal Shiny keeps the values of all the inputs from inside the modal. If you re-open it, the values are already set down the hood and even though it looks normal from the user perspective the observers are not being triggered. I tried to experiment with reactiveValues to overcome that but with no luck so far.

A minimal example showing the problem posted below. Steps to reproduce:

- Open the modal
- Check "Yes"
- Cancel or submit
- re-open
- select "Yes"

Now the second part of the questionnaire is not shown.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyJS)

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    actionButton("open", "Open questionarre")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    observeEvent(input$open, {
        showModal(modalDialog(
            title = "Open the modal",
            radioButtons(
                "radio",
                "Click 'Yes' to show additinal inputs.",
                choices = c("Yes", "No"),
                selected = character(0)
            ),

            shinyjs::hidden(
                div(id = "hiddenContent",
                    checkboxGroupInput(
                        "checkboxes", "What’s up?",
                        choices = list(
                           "Good",
                           "Bad"
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            footer = tagList(
                actionButton("cancel", "Cancel", class = "btn-light-grey"),
                actionButton("submit", "Submit")
            )
        ))
    })

    # Hiding and showing mechanism
    observeEvent(input$radio, {
        print(input$radio)
        if (input$radio == "Yes") {
            shinyjs::show("hiddenContent")
        } else {
            shinyjs::hide("hiddenContent")
            reset("checkboxes")
        }
    })

    observeEvent(input$submit, {
        print("Saving")
        removeModal()
    })

    observeEvent(input$cancel, {
        print("Canceling")
        removeModal()
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```